# Storing uploaded media files in an mvc framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, file-upload, filesystems

I have a custom mvc framework going on, which include directories such as.

- public

  - index.php
- App

  - Controllers
  - Models
  - Views
- Core
- logs
- vendor

and I am building an application that accept user media upload(images, videos).
I can't really figure out where to upload the files to.

- Should I create a new folder in the root dir to house the uploads.
- Should It be stored in the views folder.
- Should I store it in the public folder.

I have never built a program that accepted uploads before so a very amateur to this. So if you can add some best practices or external resource regarding the subject matter that'll be awesome.

Wa ya ruèse!

Comment: Upload it won't be where your views are because...well, they aren't part of your app. In general, they won't really be stored alongside your application because, again, they aren't _part_ of that application. Also, avoids the problem of somebody uploading `index.php` (or whatever file you have) which will wipe out the file with same name. Other than that, it doesn't really _matter_ that much - just dump them in some `uploads` folder somewhere.